# Are `.link_edges` and `.link_faces` guaranteed to be in counterclockwise order?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, topology, bmesh

`BMVert().link_edges` and `BMVert().link_faces` seem to always be in counterclockwise order.

For example, take this cube:

[image]

```
>>> [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).verts[1].link_edges]
[1, 2, 11]

>>> [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).verts[1].link_faces]
[5, 4, 3]
```

Is this order guaranteed? The [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html) don't seem to say anything.

This question could also apply to `BMFace().verts()`, except I assume that one's probably implicitly guaranteed to be in counterclockwise order as it's used for face directions.

Answer (score 3):

**No, `.link_edges` and `.link_faces` don't seem to have any particular order guarantee.**

A counterexample is readily produced by extruding the top face of a default cube and merging the new face into a single triangle fan:

[image]

```
>>> [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).verts[1].link_edges]
[12, 13, 14, 15]

>>> [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).verts[1].link_faces]
[8, 5, 6, 7]
```

In this case, even though the normals still point outwards, the element order in `BMesh` is clockwise.

In fact, the order isn't even guaranteed to be consecutive or consistent. When the `+X` face is inset and collapsed instead,  `.link_edges` indexes opposite faces first while `.link_faces` jumps position halfway through:

[image]

```
>>> [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).verts[4].link_edges]
[12, 13, 14, 15]

>>> [i.index for i in bmesh.from_edit_mesh(C.object.data).verts[4].link_faces]
[8, 6, 7, 5]
```

Related Questions:

[Circular order of edges around vertex](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92406/circular-order-of-edges-around-vertex)

[Navigate the disk cycle, like you can navigate the loop and radial loop cycles in bmesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/navigate-the-disk-cycle-like-you-can-navigate-the-loop-and-radial-loop-cycles-i)

BMesh Design Document:

https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Modeling/BMesh/Design